# VB: List(Of List(Of String)) keeps changing the content of the outer list when I change the inner one?

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm writing a program in VB, and I need to make a list of lists (I've already figured out how to do that one).  The problem is, the outer list is going to need a different number of elements depending on other variables elsewhere in the program.

I've looped this code:

```
    Dim rep As Long = 1023
    Dim items As List(Of String)
    items.Add("First Entry")
    items.Add("Second Entry")
    items.Add("Third Entry")
    items.Add("Fourth Entry")

    '(sake of argument, these are the variables
    'that will be changing vastly earlier
    'in the program, I put them in this way to simplify
    'this part of my code and still have it work)

    Dim myList As New List(Of List(Of String))
    Dim tempList As New List(Of String)

    For index = 1 To Len(rep.ToString)
        tempList.Add(items(CInt(Mid(rep.ToString, index, 1))))
    Next

    myList.Add(tempList)
    tempList.Clear()
```

My issue is with that last part; every time I add the tempList to myList, it's fine, but when I clear tempList, it also clears the version of tempList in myList.

myList will have a count of 1, but the list inside it has a count of 0 as soon as I clear tempList.  And I have to clear tempList because I'm looping this section of code over and over, a variable number of times.

Is there a way around this?  Am I being a horrible noob?

Comment: Uhhh, `tempList` is an object _reference_, there is not an additional 'version' of the object it when you add it to `myList`.  There is an additional object reference at that time, but the references are pointing at the same object (the List).  Why do you want to clear it?

Comment: Sorry -- I missed that you're showing us the inside of a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same `tempList` each time, instead of making a new one.

You likely need to do:

```
myList.Add(tempList)
tempList = new List(Of String) ' Create a new List(Of T), don't reuse...
```